# Automation Extracting Many Passworded Archive

Tags: command-line, automation, archive

I have many 7zip Archive with same password. When I extract it, both using GUI application and command line, I must enter same password again and again. When I read the 7za command manual pages, I just found how to specify the password to add an archive, not to extract it. 7za command need us to manually type the password. Is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: Do you mean that `7za e -p mypassword ...` doesn't work?

Comment: @maaartinus That won't work as the syntax is `7z e -p{mypassword}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can write a shell script to do that.

```
PASSWORD="YOUR PASSWORD"

for archive in *.7z
do
  echo "Extracting $archive"
  7z e -p{$PASSWORD} $archive
done
```

This will simply extract every `.7z` archive in the current directory using your password.